# Flooded roads and deprived communities: QGIS route analysis function to avoid flooded roads?

Tags: qgis, network, road, route

In QGIS I am analysing the flooding of road networks. I have created a vector line layer of all the stretches of roads in my study area where high risk flood extent areas intersect them. I now want to see which deprived areas would be most impacted by calculating the shortest route to essential services (avoiding these flooded roads).

I have polygon layers of regions of deprived communities and point layers of hospital locations.

Is there a plugin or function in QGIS that allows me to calculate the shortest route (and the time it takes, if possible) to the nearest hospital from the edge of a polygon, avoiding these flooded roads (line layer)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. This Question asks a number of questions on a number of topics. I suggest you focus this on a single issue, and once you get used to the Asking/Answering model,  ask additional Questions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: QGIS contains several network analysis tools. A good introduction can be found here - https://anitagraser.com/2019/07/07/five-qgis-network-analysis-toolboxes-for-routing-and-isochrones/. While I share your frustration with the sometimes overly harsh closure of questions, you're not going to get your question re-opened by insulting the people who need to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to work on a custom network (i.e. you want to clip out roads due to flooding or other issues) you will need to create a local database of roads (OSM is good here) and then use a local routing engine such as `pg_routing` to solve your routing issue.

Note that a raster representation of your routes is of no help to you at all.